# Silverlight is web development language or window application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I am new to this technology. Actually I am confused, Silverlight, is it a web development language, desktop application or both?

Can I develop web site using Silverlight?

Comment: Please read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlight) Wikipedia article. Silverlight allows you to develop applications that are _hosted_ on a website.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: means silverlite allow desktop application only.AM i right?

Comment: No, Silverlight is intended to be used in web applications. You need a web site to host and run your Silverlight application.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson:thank you for giving me suck kind of information

Comment: @AndersGustafsson — It was, [not so much any more](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/building-an-out-of-browser-application)

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is a subset of WPF. WPF is used for Windows based application and silverlight is used for web based application. However both use XAML language from UI perspective. **http://www.lynda.com/** has nice videos for learning Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I am confused SilverLight is web development language or desktop application or both?

Both (as well as being usable for development targeting XBox 360) … although its use for client side web development is something of a joke (as it is like less well supported Flash).